# Import PHP string into MySQL database directly instead of writing and importing file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string of data that I import into my database via command line. Right now I save data to a file, import the file, and then delete the file.

Is there a way I can import it directly?

```
$data = '...';
file_put_contents('temp.sql', $data);
exec('mysql ... < temp.sql');
unlink('temp.sql');
```

Comment: Show an example of the data. I'm going to say yes, but it's a question of would it be better as a straight query, loop with parameters, or something else. Definitely look into [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to find out how to use database connections.

Comment: The data string is very large and contains tens of thousands of inserts.

Comment: Probably yes, and yes, you can do plenty of inserts via multiple methods.  But as said, need to see samples of the data file itself.

Comment: My answer below (downvoted for some reason?!) should sort it.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: You dont have to show us your real data, a *relevant* example would do!

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it the way that you have written, using php and executing mysql as an external program using exec, you can use mysql's command line -e option:

`$data = 'insert 1; insert 2;';
exec("mysql ... -e '$data'");`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute

I wonder if perhaps you'd be better off using bash or similar?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the `mysqli_multi_query()` function which allows you to execute multiple queries with one string?

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Run queries */
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $data) === TRUE) {
    echo "It worked";
} else {
    echo "It didn't work";
}
```

If the string is too large for some reason you could split it by the semicolon `;` into an array and then iterate over it. Substitute the final block of code for:

```
$queries = explode(";",$data);
foreach ($queries as $q) {
    mysqli_query($link, $q);
}
```